# Enable the MFA for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication, graph-explorer

I'm developing a solution for my company.
Current situation:
The application can register the new user to the Azure AD B2C and the Multi Factor Authentication Status are all Disabled. (I've seen it by get to Azure AD B2C > Users > Per-user multifactor authentication), it is disabled as the default.
My task is:

- If the User choose to have the MFA methods, then I can ask for how they want to make the MFA (email, sms, authentication app etc.), then I *guess* that the Multi Factor Authentication status in the List will also be changed from Disabled to Enabled. (That is what I'm expecting about the MFA).
- Also, I'm not sure if the MFA of an user is Enable, will that always ask the user to confirm it with sms, phone or authentication app right when the user trying to login? Or doing some special task?

I have been reading in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) about that: as far as I can understand, then it is possible to add the email, phone, alternate phone by sending request through the Microsoft Graph API. So what I'm expecting is it will also change the MFA status in the **Per-user multifactor authentication**

If you have ever using this feature, please let me know or show me some useful tutorial.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To Enable multifactor authentication in Azure Active Directory B2C please refer the below document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Different methods:

[image]

Hope this helps.